# QT5 error: Unknown type name 'QCoreApplication'. First program in Qt5

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt5, qapplication, qcoreapplication

I have just installed QTCreator in Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I clicked on File->New Project->Application->QTConsole Application. A first.pro file and main.cpp file was made.

The first.pro contains:

```
QT -= gui declarative
QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

The main.cpp contains:

```
 #include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    return a.exec();
}
```

The error comes in QCoreApplication line.

Comment: hangon - you installed `qtcreator` IDE? or the whole Qt package -e.g: https://www.qt.io/offline-installers ?

Comment: meant to add click the "Qt 5.x.x offline installer link" then choose linux host. This downloads a run file (you can run on the command line) - it should install all the libraries and everything you need (except maybe gcc). If you just install QtCreator then you are probably missing the actual Qt libraries....

Answer (score 8):

The reason is that new versions of Qtcreator on Ubuntu 20.04 install `clang-10`, but it still needing `clang-8`.

*Install clang-8 package:*

```
apt install clang-8
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error is an open red circle, the code will still build.

If you want to get rid of the open red circles, go into Help->About Plugins and uncheck the Clang code model plugin. Then restart QT creator.